# Union of elements from different tuples in python

Tags: python, tuples

I have 3 tuples:

```
a = ('mary', 'peter', 'james')
b = ('brown_eyes', 'blue_eyes', 'green-eyes')
c = ('blond_hair', 'short_hair', 'dark_hair')
```

I need to join the first element of each tuple, the second element of each tuple, the third one... In order to print something like this:

```
mary brown_eyes blond_hair
peter blue_eyes short_hair
james green_eyes dark_hair
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to do this combination for you. It accepts multiple iterables and will return an iterable where each result contains an element from each of the inputs just as you have described.

```
d,e,f = zip(a,b,c)
```

Here is a complete example using your input data:

```
a = ('mary', 'peter', 'james')
b = ('brown_eyes', 'blue_eyes', 'green-eyes')
c = ('blond_hair', 'short_hair', 'dark_hair')

d,e,f = zip(a,b,c)
```

Then you can print each of these using `print` and expanding the tuple:

```
print(*d) # mary brown_eyes blond_hair
```

If you want, you can also do this in one line if you don't care about the intermediate values and just want to print the combinations.

```
_ = [print(*item) for item in zip(a,b,c)]
# mary brown_eyes blond_hair
# peter blue_eyes short_hair
# james green-eyes dark_hair
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a loop and index into each (Makes for easily readable code)

```
a=('mary', 'peter', 'james')
b=('brown_eyes','blue_eyes','green-eyes')
c=('blond_hair','short_hair','dark_hair')

for i in range(len(a)):
    print a[i], b[i], c[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution is:

```
a = ['mary', 'peter', 'james']
b = ['brown_eyes', 'blue_eyes', 'green-eyes']
c = ['blond_hair', 'short_hair', 'dark_hair']

for element in zip(a, b, c):
    print(' '.join(element))
```